# multi process to change file model, will this cause competition?

Tags: python, operating-system

multi process at the same time to change **file mode**(or something others' file meta data) like this, will this cause **undefined state**?

```py
from multiprocessing import process
import os
import stat
func = stat.fchmod
p1 = process(func, args=("somefile", stat.S_IEXEC))
p2 = process(func, args=("somefile", stat.S_IREAD))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
# what this will be, some random value or decided by which process executed last?

os.stat("somefile").ST_MODE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above code you could end up in one of the following cases:

1. User has execute permission on "somefile"
2. User has read permission on "somefile"
3. User has **both** read and execute permission on "somefile"

The reason is that there is a race condition due to the non-atomicity of the underlying C chmod implementation. Examining the source code for the [chmod](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/chmod.c#n267) utility:

```
if (ok)
{
  old_mode = file_stats->st_mode;
  new_mode = mode_adjust (old_mode, S_ISDIR (old_mode) != 0, umask_value,
                          change, NULL);

  if (! S_ISLNK (old_mode))
    {
      if (chmodat (fts->fts_cwd_fd, file, new_mode) == 0)
        chmod_succeeded = true;
      else
        {
          if (! force_silent)
            error (0, errno, _("changing permissions of %s"),
                   quoteaf (file_full_name));
          ok = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The `mode_adjust` function is implemented in gnulib’s modechange.c. It turns bits in the old mode on or off according to the requested change, and returns the new mode value. 
When the two chmod operations run in parallel, it might be the case that both of them fetch the original mode of the original file; then they both calculate the required new_mode. On the other hand, it could also be that the two chmod execute sequentially and thus the final mode of the file is the "sum" of the two operations.